# Problem 'unable to open datasource" with ogr2ogr to reproject shapefile

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I have no idea why I get the following error:

```
Unable to open datasource `Sydney2.shp' with the following drivers.
```

I have already checked successfully the shape with `ogrinfo`.

I am using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" Sydney.shp Sydney2.shp -s_srs EPSG:32656 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting to convert data in Sydney.shp to Sydney2.shp with a different SRS. However that isn't what you're doing.

> ```
>    Usage: ogr2ogr [--help-general] [-skipfailures] [-append] [-update]
>                   [-select field_list] [-where restricted_where]
>                   [-progress] [-sql <sql statement>] [-dialect dialect]
>                   [-preserve_fid] [-fid FID]
>                   [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax]
>                   [-a_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-s_srs srs_def]
>                   [-f format_name] [-overwrite] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...]
>                   dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
>                   [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name] [-nlt type] [-dim 2|3] [layer [layer ...]]
> ```

Note that the destination comes first, so you're asking it to copy from Sydney2.shp to Sydney.shp. You probably wanted:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" Sydney2.shp Sydney.shp -s_srs EPSG:32656 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

Comment: Thanx, thats it. I have to change the position of the source and destination file. Quite easy, i better read the syntax more closely next time :-E

Comment: You are not the only one. GDAL is using target-source order in most vector tools but source-target in raster tools.

Comment: Indeed its a problem that some of us have seen before :-)

Comment: I was almost struggling for half an hour with a stupid bug. I was putting the input and ouput the other way around. Thanks buddy! you saved my morning! :D